# Adding SVN revision and build number from Jenkins with GruntJS

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs

I've just started to use Gruntjs over visual studio build scripts for some js projects.
The only thing i would still like to be able to do that haven't figured out is append an environmental variable into a banner.

For example in the gruntFile.js i have..

```
concat: {
        options: {
            separator: '',
            banner: '/*!\n My App v<%= pkg.version %> \n Date: <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy MM:hh:ss") %> \n Revision: */\n'
        },
        basic_and_extras: {
            .....
        }
    }
```

I'm using Jenkins as Build server and there are two environmental variables available:

SVN_REVISION
    Subversion revision number that's currently checked out to the workspace, such as "12345"

BUILD_NUMBER
    The current build number, such as "153"

What i would like to do is find a way to pick up this and add it to the banner. (or package.json)?

Is this possible?

Comment: Jenkins allows you to run any BATCH or shell script as a build step, so you should be able to script this and pass those env vars to the script at build time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that grunt tasks are just Node. You can just get the environment variable from `process.env`:

```
concat: {
    options: {
        separator: '',
        banner: '/*!\n My App v<%= pkg.version %> \n Date: <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy MM:hh:ss") %> \n Revision: ' + process.env.SVN_REVISION + ' */\n'
    },
    basic_and_extras: {
        .....
    }
}
```